# delphi xe ide -help manual "Un-installation"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Please suggest registry entry of delphi XE help system as it is pointing to wrong drive due and not opening in ide as my hard drive partition no longer exists where it was installed previously.even re-installation not working as it is asking for remove

Comment: Reinstallation is the easiest way forward

Comment: i tried re-installation but setup offers modify and repair option and in repair  it asks for old path which doesn't exists due to partition failure on hard disk

Comment: Uninstall completely. And then start again.

Comment: while uninstalling a error comes invalid drive y:\ and after that a meesage pops unable to uninstall old version of XE help system>please unistall yourself using control panel.

Comment: yes.it opens same Embacadero installation with repair and remove option which both throws y:\ error as installation exists over there before drive failure

Comment: You'll probably need to remove it from the registry and install again. Or rename the drive temporarily to get the uninstall to fly.

Comment: where the help is installed in registry that i want to know.Please suggest

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/401511/how-to-remove-a-broken-program-from-the-programs-and-features-list-in-windows-7

Comment: The problem with earlier XE versions of Delphi is that Help files were integrated into Windows help system. So you won't find a simple registry entry under the Embarcadero section in registry. So I guess the quickest way would be to map a virtual drive to specific path so that uninstaller has access to desired files in order to uninstall the Delphi help files.

Comment: ok thanks that link helped